# Weak hypothesis for Morera's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

Morera's theorem states that : Let $f(z)$ is a continous in a domain $D$. If $\int_Cf(z)dz = 0$ for every simple closed contour lying in $D,$ then $f$ is analytic in $D$.

Does there exist a function $f$ such that $\int _C f(z)dz$ is nonzero for exactly one simple closed curve $C$ but $f$ is not analytic?

I have tried some examples like $1/z$ does not work. Are there are examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be. If $f$ is continuous, the map

$$C \mapsto \int_C f(z) dz$$ is continuous. Therefore if $\int_{C_1} f(z) dz \neq 0$ for a given curve $C_1$, it will also be the case for $C$ close enough to $C_1$.

*Note: you need to choose a topology to make rigorous $C$ close to $C_1$.*